# Inconsistency between %%timeit and time() in notebooks

Tags: python, performance, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I was reading [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/do-you-have-these-python-speedup-skills-3fd9e7758765) and I tried some of their tricks to see how they work. The first item speak about global variables, this is the code:

```
#bad code

import math

size = 10000
for x in range(size):
    for y in range(size):
        z = math.sqrt(x) + math.sqrt(y)
```

```
#good code

import math

def main():
  size = 10000
  for x in range(size):
    for y in range(size):
      z = math.sqrt(x) + math.sqrt(y)

main()
```

I'm working with Google Colab and when I measure the time with `%%timeit` I don't found differences:

[Execution times here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1B07.png)

After talking to the writer of the article I saw that he had found differences, he used the function `time()` to measure the time, when i tried it i found the differences:

[Execution times here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shvs9.png)

I can understand that there are differences between `%%timeit` and `time()`. But that with `%%timeit` there is no time difference and with `time()` yes, I do not understand.

Thanks for the time!

Comment: I believe the difference is causes by using local (to function `main`) variables as opposed to global ones. `%%timeit` makes its own context thus turning your global variables into local ones as well.

Answer (score -1):

**%%timeit** provides a simple way to time small bits of Python code, it is specifically for running performance tests, while **time()** has access to various time/date functions provided by the underlying system.